# generate dataframe of model predictions by looping through dictionary of models

Tags: loops, dictionary, scikit-learn

I would like to loop through a dictionary like this:

```
models = {'OLS': LinearRegression(),
         'Lasso': Lasso(),
         'LassoCV': LassoCV(n_alphas=300, cv=3)}
```

and then i want to generate a dataframe of the each model's predictions.

So far I wrote this to code, which only generates arrays of each result:

```
predictions = []

for i in models:   
    predictions.append(models[i].fit(X_train,y_train).predict(X_test))
```

As the final result, I want a dataframe with each column labelled by the key in the dictionary and the result values associated with the model key name inside the column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the `predictions` to the list, you can directly insert the `predictions` into a data frame.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
models = {'OLS': LinearRegression(),
         'Lasso': Lasso(),
         'LassoCV': LassoCV(n_alphas=300, cv=3)}
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in models:
  df[i] = models[i].fit(X_train,y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Comment: thank you! I have a long way to go before I can think fluently in python. really appreciate your help :-)

Comment: If this answered the question to your satisfaction feel free to accept and upvote it. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.